# DSC File Resource - copy file

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm using a PowerShell DSC Pull Server.
It's possible to use the File resource to copy a file every time is modified?
I've tried the below:

```
        File Test{
        DestinationPath = "c:\yyy\test.txt"
        SourcePath = "\\share\test.txt"
        Ensure = "Present"
        Type = "File"
        Credential = $Credential
        Checksum = "modifiedDate"
        Force = $true}
```

but no luck: if I modify the file from SourcePath I'd expect that the destination file should be updated too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add MatchSource, See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/reference/resources/windows/fileResource).

```
    File Test{
        DestinationPath = "c:\yyy\test.txt"
        SourcePath = "\\share\test.txt"
        Ensure = "Present"
        Type = "File"
        Credential = $Credential
        Checksum = "modifiedDate"
        Force = $true
        MatchSource = $true
    }
```